# i got an error while execute the index.html

Tags: javascript, async-await

```js
//executor
//produce promises

const pobj1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let rollno = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    resolve(rollno);
    //reject('Error while communicating');
  }, 2000);
});

const getBiodata = (indexvalue) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout((indexvalue) => {
      let biodata = {
        name: 'Rajua',
        age: 12
      }
      resolve(`My rool ${indexvalue} and my name is ${biodata.name} 
                my age is ${biodata.age}`)
      console.log(`My name is ${biodata.name}`);
    }, 2000, indexvalue);

  });
}

async function getdata() {
  const rollNoData = await pobj1;
  console.log(rollNoData);

  const bdata = await getBiodata(rollno[1]);
  console.log(bdata);
}
getdata();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>hello</h1>
  <!-- promises has 3 stage
    task=app mujhe promise karoki kal 10am mein call karoge.
stage1-Pending
evnt time hogeya 10 am 
call karoge ya nehi,
success or failure,
fulfilled or reject.
stage2-resolve-fulfilled 
stage3-reject-->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `rollno[1]` should be `rollNoData[1]`

Comment: thanks it runs fine and i got the output.

Comment: @Barmar rewrite your comment as a response

Comment: @RoyalGoose I voted to close the question as a typo, I don't consider this worthy of a response.